# $g(x)=f(4^x,0)$, $f(a,b)=f(a+b,b-a)$. Show that $\exists$ a constant $c$ such that $g(x+c)=g(x)$ for all real $x$.

Tags: functions, proof-verification, polynomials, proof-writing, functional-equations

> **Question :**
>
> Suppose $f$ is a function of two variables which satisfies : $$f(a,b)=f(a+b,b-a) \quad \forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}$$ Show that $\exists$ a constant $c$ such that $g(x+c)=g(x) ~ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ given that $g(x)=f(4^x,0)$

---

The problem can be solved as:

Using $f(a,b)=f(a+b,b-a)$ repeatedly, we get:

$$g(x)=f(4^x,0)\tag1$$

$$=f(4^x, -4^x)\tag2$$

$$=f(0,-2\cdot 4^x)\tag3$$

$$=f(2 \cdot 4^x, -2 \cdot 4^x)\tag4$$

$$=f(0,-4.4^x)=f(0,-4^{x+1})\tag5$$

$$=f(4^{x+1}, -4^{x+1})\tag6$$

$$.$$

$$.$$

$$.$$

$$= f(4^{x+c}, -4^{x+c})\tag7$$

$$=f(4^{x+c}+0, 0 -4^{x+c})\tag8$$

$$=f(4^{x+c},0)=g(x+c)\tag9$$

Doesn't this imply that the problem is solved? And doesn't it imply that any $c\in \mathbb{Z^+}+\{0\}$ satisfy?

Comment: I took the liberty of numbering your equations so that they could be referred to.

Comment: As to me, that would result in $f(0,-2\cdot4^x)$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Well, that would result into $f(0, -2\cdot 4^x)$ but then it would result into $(3)$. I didn't see it. Okay, give me some time. Let me re edit the question.

Comment: As it stands now, you have a wrong move between (3) and (4).

Comment: @IvanNeretin Seriously, I was just hurrying and messed up that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's stay with $(a,b)$ a little longer.
$$f(a,b)=f(a+b,b-a)=\\
=f(2b,-2a)=f(2b-2a,-2a-2b)=\\
=f(-4a,-4b)=f(-4a-4b,4a-4b)=\\
=f(-8b,8a)=f(8a-8b,8a+8b)=\\
=f(16a,16b)$$
That's about the size of it. So the minimal period of $f(4^x,0)$ is $\bf2$, not 1.